# Run a command in Java

Tags: java, command-line, command

I want to  run the command `mvn liquibase:update` if the user of the application sends the word run as command. How can I do it?

I already tried the following

```
   if (args[0].equals("run")) {
            Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            try {
                Process pr = rt.exec("mvn liquibase:update");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

but I get the following error

```
ava.io.IOException: Cannot run program "mvn": CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não conseguiu localizar o ficheiro especificado
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1142)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1073)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:415)
    at java.base/java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:312)
    at com.petapilot.migrations.MigrationsApplication.main(MigrationsApplication.java:25)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não conseguiu localizar o ficheiro especificado
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(ProcessImpl.java:483)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:158)
    at java.base/java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1109)
    ... 5 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead;

```
Process pr = rt.exec("cmd /c mvn liquibase:update");
```

Comment: it worked but the only provided feedback is "Process finished with code 0". Is it possible to present the output of that command if runned in the console?